# Dimension too large Error in bar drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is my code. The following code returned ‘Dimension too large’ error. This error has different reasons since I cannot fix it after I surfed on the internet.

The code would be work if I ‘change the turns’ of values of x-axis and y-axis.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xlabel=Population,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    xbar interval=1E-12,
    ymin=-1,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(1E-3,1930) (1E-6,1940)
         (1E-9,1950) };
%
%\addplot 
%   coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6) 
%       (1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
%
%\addplot 
%   coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6) 
%       (1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};
\legend{Far}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure you're not looking for `semilogxaxis`? Does it even make sense to use logarithmic scaling for the y-axis here?